# Why stderr is required?

Tags: linux, stdout, stderr

```
  $ tty
  /dev/tty0
```

On

```
      $cat
```

in user-space, cat process waits on it's stdin to receive input from /dev/tty0 file.

On listing non-existent file fff,

```
  ls /fff > file1
   ls cannot find file :file1 Access denied
```

Despite redirection of stdout to file1 instead of /dev/tty0, the error about, file does not exist, will display on /dev/tty0 through stderr file descriptor.

---

Question:

If stderr writes to /dev/tty0 similar to stdout, what is the purpose of stderr?

What was the idea behind,  UNIX/Linux maintaining one more file descriptor stderr for writing error to /dev/tty0 ?

Comment: You asked the `stdout` to be redirected to a file AND not the `stderr`. Meaning, `stderr` is still going to the terminal, /dev/tty0. So what's the issue here?

Comment: @RakeshSharma I did not get you. My question is not about knowing the mechanics in usage of stdout/stderr, but try knowing why do we need stderr, because it is also writing to /dev/tty0

Comment: Demonstrably it isn't in your example...

Comment: @MichaelHomer ok updated query. Bit lazy today

Comment: [Deeply related, possible duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247162/what-is-regarded-as-ideal-in-relation-to-using-stdout-stderr-for-output-in-dif)

Answer (score 3):

We need STDERR (file descriptor 2) to separate the output stream (STDOUT, file descriptor 1) from the error stream.

Without the separation, you can not distinguish the valid outputs from errors.

As you can see in your case, both streams are being attached to the terminal, and you can easily distinguish or operate on them (`dup(2)` et al.) by simple file descriptor operations from userspace.

Just an an example, to send STDOUT to a file and STDERR to a different file:

```
my_command >stdout.log 2>stderr.log
```

Answer (score -3):

`stdoout` is expected to be opened in a write-only state for every unix process from launch, `stdin` as read-only (as i think), and `stderr` as non-blocking read/write deploying - at maximum - a line out-buffer.

`stderr` is primarily for getting output to a consumer immediately, and is heavily relied upon in terminal user interface applications; have a look at more.

Comment: Both Read/write from stderr?

Comment: According to the manpage on Arch Linux, `stderr` is unbuffered, while `stdout` is line-buffered. Further, I am almost completely certain that there is no system where by default `stderr` is RW but `stdout` is write-only. I'm open to learning otherwise though — any chance you could cite some sources on this?